# Criminal record certificate from USA

Tags: criminal-records

I live in New Zealand now. 10 years ago I lived in USA for about 10 months. How can I get police certificate from USA now? I am a third party national.

Comment: You should find out from whoever needs the document whether it needs an apostille. If needed, you would need to find out from the FBI how to request a copy that is eligible for an apostille.

Comment: @GerardAshton FBI is a federal agency, the DoS certifies federal documents.

Comment: Yes, it would be the Department of State that would certify an FBI document, but the document would have to be in the right form for them to certify it.

Comment: no need to anything. I just need criminal record.

Comment: If you don't need to show it to anyone, you just want it to look at with your own eyes, then there is no need for an apostille. But if you need to show it to someone and expect them to believe it's a real FBI document, that's a different story.

Comment: I want to show and they dont need apostile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File the [FBI request here](https://www.fbi.gov/how-we-can-help-you/more-fbi-services-and-information/identity-history-summary-checks), they'll provide a criminal background certification for you.

Comment: Who downvoted you. This is correct answer